# The ApplicationDeployment class is not supported in .NET 6 so can't access ClickOnce data folder

Tags: directory, clickonce

Re https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/accessing-local-and-remote-data-in-clickonce-applications?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp

In .Net6, how can I get access to the ClickOnce data folder from my deployed app, if the ApplicationDeployment class is not available???

Surely this is a major issue?? I am developing Winforms in C#.

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 1):

See the discussion here for accessing ClickOnce from .Net applications:
[Allow apps to access ClickOnce deployment properties](https://github.com/dotnet/deployment-tools/pull/208)